# No article before "class"

Tags: articles

> She came to class.

Is it correct?

Why isn't any article used before "class"? Can I write:

> She came to the class.

Please tell.

Answer (score 4):

Some nouns that refer to places do not normally have an article when they are being used to refer to the purpose of a place.

In the sentence "She came to class", the word class refers to a place for study. It doesn't require an article. "She came to the class" is also correct, if you need to emphasise that the class has been determined. (Meaning "the class that we both know of"). Also, use "the" or "a" if referring to a physical object. "There are 15 boys in the class".

Other examples:

> I go to school everyday
>
> She was in prison for 5 years
>
> I never attend church
>
> Jack took the cow to market

See http://www.grammaring.com/the-zero-article-with-places